# PyGTK moving widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I would like to know if I can re-edit the coordinate of `fixed.put(image, xx, yy)` after starting the application ?

```
xx = 100
yy = 100

def callback(window, event):

    print ('Clicked at x=', event.x, "and y=", event.y)
    image.show()
    GLib.timeout_add(100, image.hide)
    fixed.put(image, xx, yy)
```

For now here my output :

```
(python.exe:11204): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:05:03.097: gtk_fixed_put: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) == NULL' failed
```

Thank you.

Comment: From the error message, you already set image inside a container. Assuming it is in the fixed, you shall use `fixed.move(image,xx,yy)`

Comment: Relevant [how-to-drag-images-with-pygtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852359/how-to-drag-images-with-pygtk), [Gtk.Fixed.move](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Fixed.html#Gtk.Fixed.move)

Comment: @Nico238 YES, That what i needed, thank you.